# How to write english and arabic in same line without corrupting the format

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, arabic

i am writing an Arabic text and i want to insert an English word in the sentence, as follows:

**وأنوى تغييرها إلى وشىء آخر Access أنا استخدم قاعدة البيانات**

but when trying to accomplish this in  Microsoft word 2010 when switching to English the cursor goes to the beginning of the line:

**أنا أستخدم قاعدة البيانات Access**

how to accomplish that please.

Comment: Perhaps it's because, in English and other languages, text is written from left to right, and that's the end of the line.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613613/why-words-are-shuffled-when-i-insert-english-words-in-any-arabic-urdu-persian-te (where the answers are not perfect but I’ll try to improve them).

Answer (score 5):

We need to enable the RTL for writing arabic and english together.

open word document just Press Right CTRL+SHIFT which enables RTL

Start typing Arabic by changing the keyboard then again English by changing the keyboard layout.

You will have to enable the RTL throught the document.

Comment: Is there any indication on the interface window of RTL mode?